# How can I prove that this polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

How can I prove that $x^5+6x^3+x^2+3x+2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

I tried with Eisenstein (also making the substitution $x\mapsto x-1$ and $x\mapsto x+1$ to see if I obtain an Eisenstein polynomial) but nothing. If we go modulo 2 we obtain a reducible polynomial, and modulo 3 we obtain $x^5+x^2+2$ and I don't know how to prove that it is irreducible.

Any help?

Comment: There is always brute force.  Modulo 3 there are only so many polynomials it could reduce to a product of, so you might check them all.

Comment: It's irreducible in $\mathbb F_{41}$.

Comment: @JBeardz - Is the brute force the only way to solve this problem?

Comment: mod 3, isn't $x^5 + x^2 + 2 \equiv 2(x^2+1)$? $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$... the equivalence is by Fermat

Comment: @Victor No not at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the rational root theorem the only possible rational roots are $\pm 1, \pm 2$, and by inspection none of these are roots. If the polynomial is reducible, it therefore factors into the product of a quadratic and cubic factor (over $\mathbb{Z}$ by Gauss's lemma).

$\bmod 2$ the polynomial factors as $x(x^4 + x + 1)$. The latter factor has no root $\bmod 2$, so if it is reducible it is the product of two irreducible quadratics. But the only irreducible quadratic $\bmod 2$ is $x^2 + x + 1$, and $(x^2 + x + 1)^2 = x^4 + x^2 + 1$. Hence $x^4 + x + 1$ is irreducible $\bmod 2$.

But if the polynomial factored as the product of a qudaratic and cubic factor over $\mathbb{Z}$, it would only have at most cubic irreducible factors $\bmod 2$; contradiction. Hence the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: Scooped me by a minute...*precisely* the same answer!